# Torus inside $S^2\times S^2$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have a torus $\mathbb{T}^2$ inside $S^2\times S^2$, i.e., there exists a continuous injective function $\phi:S^1\times S^1\rightarrow S^2\times S^2$. Is it always true that this torus can be seen as $\phi(S^1\times S^1)=C_1\times C_2$ where $C_1$ is a circle inside $S^2$ and $C_2$ is a circle inside $S^2$?

I am not sure if this is true or not its just something I have been thinking about. I tried to construct said circles but I didn't get much further. Since there isnt a continuous map from the $2$-torus to $S^2$ we know that there must exist a point $p\in S^1$ such that $\phi(S^1 \times \{p\})$ is non-trivial inside $S^2$ and we can try and use this to create said circle, but this restriction does not need to be injective.

I am just unsure how to approach this, any insight is appreciated.

Comment: My guess is *No!* Consider the following. Embed the torus into $\Bbb{R}^3$ in the well known way, and then $\Bbb{R}^3$ into $\Bbb{R}^2\times \Bbb{R}^2$ in a way that the projection of the torus in the other factor is an annulus (e.g. project the donut down to the plane $z=0$). Then embed both copies of $\Bbb{R}^2$ into their respective one-point-compactifications, i.e. into $S^2\times S^2$. Then the projection of the torus onto one copy of $S^2$ still looks like an annulus, no?

Comment: (cont'd) The range of $z$-coordinates of the torus in $\Bbb{R}^3$ is a line segment (the fourth coordinate is a constant), and that is what the projection into the other $S^2$ will look like?

Comment: Similarly to @JyrkiLahtonen's suggestion, you can use the fact that there are knotted tori in $\mathbb R^4$. Once you have an example in $\mathbb R^4$, compactify the ambient space to $S^2\times S^2$.

Comment: Ah alright thanks to both of you !

Comment: By "circle" do you mean "loop"? If you mean circle specifically, then consider any product of noncircular (non-self-intersecting) loops - this will be a torus too!